# Calculate payment date for each invoice

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Please consider the following table `transaction`: a company regularly sends invoices to their customers that are part of the same order. The companies' clients will often pay only once per so many weeks.

(`trans_date` in format `yyyy-mm-dd`)

```
id    order_id    trans_type    trans_date    trans_amount
----------------------------------------------------------
1        1          invoice     2017-01-10        100
2        1          invoice     2017-05-23        150
3        1          invoice     2017-05-28        200
4        2          invoice     2017-03-01        700
5        2          payment     2017-06-16        700
6        1          payment     2017-10-12        450
7        3          invoice     2017-06-24        199
```

The company would like to see on what date each invoice was paid for. For example: invoice (`id`) 1 (part of `order_id=1` group) was sent on `2017-01-10` and paid on `2017-10-12` (`id=6)`. Invoice with `id=7` has not been paid at all.

The desired output would be the payment date for each invoice (`payment_date`):

```
id    order_id    trans_type    trans_date    trans_amount    payment_date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        1          invoice     2017-01-10        100         2017-10-12
2        1          invoice     2017-05-23        150         2017-10-12
3        1          invoice     2017-05-28        200         2017-10-12
4        2          invoice     2017-03-01        700         2017-06-16
5        2          payment     2017-06-16        700
6        1          payment     2017-10-12        450
7        3          invoice     2017-06-24        199
```

For transactions 5, 6 and 7, the `payment_date` is empty because it is either a payment (`id=5` and `6`) or an unpaid invoice (`id=7`).

I don't understand how I should solve this issue. In combination with regular scripting, I would get the whole set and loop through it to find each payment. But how can this be solved in SQL only?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: there is a possible scenario where the payment was just on part of the amount? in your example say that payment id (6) will be 357 ? if not and excluding some other edge cases I think it's possible

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added some tags. I'm using SQL Server 2012. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Mzf There is indeed a theoretical possibility of a payment being only part of the amount, but these are exceptions. Very good catch, but I don't see how this could be accounted for, so I left it out of the question. For now, I'm assuming all payments will be in full.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a simple left join? 
Below code is standard SQL.

```
Select a.id ,   a.order_id,    a.trans_type,    a.trans_date,    a.trans_amount,    isnull(b.trans_date, '')  As payment_date
From transaction a
Left join transaction b
On a.order_id = b.order_id
And a.trans_type = 'invoice' 
And b.trans_type = 'payment'
```

Comment: If I do this, the number of rows in the output increases. In reality, I have 50'000 rows in table `transactions` but when left joining the table to itself, the output is about 70'000 rows. What is a possible explanation?

Comment: Only possible situation I can think of is that there are more than one `payment` row for a single `order_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a cumulative sum of payments and invoices and get the first date when the payment total meets or exceeds the invoice total:

```
with ip as (
      select ip.*,
             sum(case when ip.trans_type = 'invoice' then ip.trans_amount else 0 end) over (order by ip.trans_date) as running_invoice,
             sum(case when ip.trans_type = 'payment' then ip.trans_amount else 0 end) over (order by ip.trans_date) as running_payment,
      from invoicepayments i
     )
select ip.*,
       (select min(ip2.trans_date)
        from ip ip2
        where ip2.running_payment >= ip.running_invoice and
              ip.trans_type = 'invoice'
       ) as payment_date
from ip;
```